# Перестали работать кастомные снипеты Emmet в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3, emmet

В один момент перестали работать кастомные снипеты Emmet в Sublime Text 3.

В настройки эммета очень давно не заходил, все прекрасно работало до последнего момента... Файл настроек:

```js
{
    "snippets": {
        "html": {
            "abbreviations": {
                "gjq": "<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>"
            },
            "snippets": {
                "!ru": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"ru\">\n\t<head>\n\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n\t\t<title>Document</title>\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles/style.css\">\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t\t${child}${cursor}\n\t</body>\n</html>",
                "debug12": "<div class=\"debug\">\n\t<div>\n\t\t<div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t</div>\n\t</div>\n</div>",
                "debug24": "<div class=\"debug\">\n\t<div>\n\t\t<div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t\t<div></div>\n\t\t</div>\n\t</div>\n</div>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Внятной информации найти не смог...  Якобы все правильно написал... Переустановить эммет пробовал, не работает... что это может быть?

Answer (score 0):

Теперь оно должно выглядеть вот так вот:

```js
{
    "config": {
        "html": {
            "snippets": {
                "!ru": "{<!DOCTYPE html>}+html[lang=ru]>(head>meta[charset=UTF-8]+title{Document}+meta[name=viewport content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'])+body",
                "gjq": "script[src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js]",
                "debug12": "div.debug>div>div>div*12",
                "debug24": "div.debug>div>div>div*24"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

но не очень понятно, как создавать abbreviation, как управлять курсором и тд... Что еще можно делать в новых настройках?